Heatmap in React JS
I am using ApexCharts to integrate a heatmap. However, when the Y value is 0, the default color rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) is applied. I want to set a specific color for the value y = 0 to improve the appearance.
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactApexChart from "react-apexcharts";
import data from "./data.json"; // Adjust path as per your file location
import client from "../../../services/graphql/apollo";
import { getVehicleHourlyAnalyticsListQuery } from "../../../services/graphql/queries";

const HeatMapChart = () => {
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({
    series: [],
    options: {
      chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: "heatmap",
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      colors: ["#008FFB"],
      title: {
        text: "HeatMap Chart (Single color)",
      },
      xaxis: {
        categories: [], // This will be populated with time ranges (e.g., "0:00 - 1:00")
      },
      yaxis: {
        categories: [], // This will be populated with days (e.g., "Monday", "Tuesday")
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: true,
        enabledOnSeries: undefined,
        shared: true,
        followCursor: true,
        intersect: false,
        inverseOrder: false,
        custom: undefined,
        fillSeriesColor: false,
        theme: "light",
        style: {
          fontSize: "12px",
          fontFamily: undefined,
        },
        formatter: undefined,
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 0,
        format: {
          title: function (val) {
            return val;
          },
          formatter: function (val) {
            return val;
          },
        },
        items: {
          display: "flex",
          fontFamily: undefined,
          padding: "5px 10px",
        },
        fixed: {
          enabled: false,
          position: "topRight",
          offsetX: 0,
          offsetY: 0,
        },
      },
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // Format the data for ApexCharts
    const formattedSeries = data.map((dayData) => ({
      name: dayData.name,
      data: dayData.data.map((timeData) => ({
        x: timeData.x,
        y: timeData.y,
      })),
    }));

    const categoriesX = data[0].data.map((timeData) => timeData.x); // Assuming all days have the same time ranges
    const categoriesY = data.map((dayData) => dayData.name);

    setChartData({
      series: formattedSeries,
      options: {
        ...chartData.options,
        xaxis: {
          ...chartData.options.xaxis,
          categories: categoriesX,
        },
        yaxis: {
          ...chartData.options.yaxis,
          categories: categoriesY,
        },
      },
    });
  }, []); // Empty dependency array means this effect runs once after initial render

  console.log("chartData.series::", chartData.series);

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="chart">
        <ReactApexChart  options={chartData.options} series={chartData.series} type="heatmap" height={350} />
      </div>
      {/* <div id="html-dist"></div> */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default HeatMapChart;


data.json:
[
  {
    "name": "Saturday",
    "data": [
      {
        "x": "0:00 - 1:00",
        "y": 0
      },
      {
        "x": "1:00 - 2:00",
        "y": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Sunday",
    "data": [
      {
        "x": "0:00 - 1:00",
        "y": 0
      },
      {
        "x": "1:00 - 2:00",
        "y": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Monday",
    "data": [
      {
        "x": "0:00 - 1:00",
        "y": 0
      },
      {
        "x": "1:00 - 2:00",
        "y": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Thursday",
    "data": [
      {
        "x": "0:00 - 1:00",
        "y": 0
      },
      {
        "x": "1:00 - 2:00",
        "y": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Tuesday",
    "data": [
      {
        "x": "0:00 - 1:00",
        "y": 0
      },
      {
        "x": "1:00 - 2:00",
        "y": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Friday",
    "data": [
      {
        "x": "0:00 - 1:00",
        "y": 0
      },
      {
        "x": "1:00 - 2:00",
        "y": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Wednesday",
    "data": [
      {
        "x": "0:00 - 1:00",
        "y": 0
      },
      {
        "x": "1:00 - 2:00",
        "y": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]


I tried multiple solutions few of them are:

I added a default color in the colors options
I added a condition where y === 0 than color:red

Any help would be appreciated

According to the  documentation, you can configure the plotOptions > heatmap > colorScale > ranges attribute in the chart options. In your case, you can configure it like this:
const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({
    series: [],
    options: {
      ...
      // Added options here
      plotOptions: {
        heatmap: {
          colorScale: {
            ranges: [
              {
                from: 0,
                to: 0,
                color: '#FF0000',
                name: 'If y is 0',
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });

I also created a DEMO LINK to review and test it easily. On the other hand, you can review some other examples here
Hope, it's clear and helpful

Yes, It is working Thanks

You're welcome, can you mark this post as the answer to the question since it's fixed the issue?
